# use_connect prints a read only error

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

So I have this simple script to make every bone connect to each other. (want to connect lots of unconnected bones.)

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
for bone in obj.data.bones:    
    bone.use_connect = True
```

the problem is when I run it I get this error:

```
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "use_connect" from "Bone" is read-only
```

Is there a way around this? Am I missing something?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Edit: With the help of Zack Mercury and Marty Fouts, here is the new script that works:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
for bone in obj.data.edit_bones:

    bone.use_connect = True
```

Comment: You have to switch to edit mode and set it on the edit bones I think.

Comment: adding "bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')" reports the same error

Comment: the already have a parent child link... it's even shows as a dotted line in view port.

Comment: you need to use `edit_bone`s. not `bone`s.  See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full process to do this in Python

```py
import bpy

armature = bpy.data.armatures[ARMATURE_NAME]

if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT_ARMATURE':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

parent = armature.edit_bones[PARENT_BONE_NAME]
child = armature.edit_bones[CHILD_BONE_NAME]
child.use_connect = True
```

Where you pick the NAME names appropriately.

The key thing is that you have to use the *edit* bones, not the pose bones.